# How to stitch two images have different absolute coordinates?

Tags: opencv

for example, stitch

```
first image
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1

second image
2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2

and What I want
0 0 0 2 2 2 2
1 1 1 2 2 2 2 
1 1 1 2 2 2 2
1 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

or

```
1 1 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 2 2 2 2 
1 1 1 2 2 2 2
0 0 0 2 2 2 2
```

In python, that is easy to make like..

```
temp_panorama = np.zeros((1's height+abs(2's upper part length), 1's width+2's width))
temp_panorama[(2's upper part length) : 1's height, 0 : 1's width] = img1[:]
temp_panorama[0 : 2's height, 1's width +1 :] = img2[:, :]
```

but how can I implement the same function in C++'s opencv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use subimages:

```
// ROI where first image will be placed
cv::Rect firstROI = cv::Rect(x1,y2, first.cols, first.height);
cv::Rect secondROI = cv::Rect(x2,y2, second.cols, second.height);

// create an image big enought to hold the result
cv::Mat canvas = cv::Mat::zeros(cv::Size(std::max(x1+first.cols, x2+second.cols), std::max(y1+first.rows, y2+second.rows)), first.type());

// use subimages:
first.copyTo(canvas(firstROI));
second.copyTo(canvas(secondROI));
```

in your example:

```
x1 = 0, 
y1 = 1, 
x2 = 3, 
y2 = 0
```

first.cols == 3
first.rows == 3
second.cols == 4
second.rows == 3

Comment: I'm sorry for the late choice. If I copy the matrix using copyTo, can I add it to the overlapping parts?